# Timer "Name" propertiy ? Window Form c#?

Tags: winforms

In window forms, can we access name property of timer control or can we change the name property. Help me thank you.

Comment: what's the question? name property of what? this is not clear

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class, then there is no such property within this class or its ancestors. If you need one, just create your own timer based on System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Comment: hi Thank Mr.Max can you give me any reference, like this scenario

Comment: @Ssasidhar I am not sure if we are on the same page here, since I don't know your background. Looks like you are a beginner in the software development. Hence I would suggest to start from the beginning. Try to read about OOP concepts. And then apply this knowledge in terms of WinForms and C#.